# List of GraphObject properties for facebook api

Tags: php, facebook

this might be an easy one but about 15 searches in I can't find what I am looking for. I'm getting started with the facebook API's and am familiar with the basics GraphUser class, I can pull users basic information. I found that there are additional properties that can be read through the getProperty function.

On this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0 it shows

```
// User example
echo $object->getProperty('name');
echo $user->getName();

// Location example
echo $object->getProperty('country');
echo $loc->getCountry();
```

I know gender is another property it can pull. I'm wondering if there is a list of what these properties are that I can read or if there is a page that explains what these properties are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the PHP SDK is based on the Graph API I'd assume you will want to look at the API reference for each object https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/